# Create a new column based on group conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm struggling on creating a column where the context is as follows:
I have a dataset of basketball games, and I have play-by-play information, one of this information is whether the shot was converted, if it was results in "1" otherwise "0". I need to create a column containing information whether the last shot of the same player on the current line in a given game was converted or not. Below is a toy example, showing the expected results in the `prev_shot` column. Note that in the first line of the shot (when we have no history) `prev_shot` is equal to "1".

```
dat_ = data.frame(game = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                  player = c("A","B","A","B","C","D","B", "D", "D"),
                  shot = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0),
                  prev_shot = c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0));dat_
  game player shot prev_shot
1    1      A    0         1
2    1      B    1         1
3    1      A    1         0
4    1      B    0         1
5    2      C    1         1
6    2      D    1         1
7    2      B    0         1
8    2      D    0         1
9    2      D    0         0
```

Any hint on how can I create the column `prev_shot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want the last value for that group, we can use `lag`.
It seems the OP wants a 1 for the first value, so I used `default = 1`, this can be changed as needed

**With dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

dat_ |> 
    mutate(prev_shot = lag(shot, default = 1), .by = c(game, player))
```